# Printing two records one beside other per one page

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Can I print two records one beside other in one landscape page ?

Example:

```
Page1

Record1                                      Record2
..............................               ...........................
..............................               ...........................
..............................               ...........................
..............................               ...........................

Page2

Record3                                      Record4
..............................               ...........................
..............................               ...........................
..............................               ...........................
..............................               ...........................
```

Comment: Nothing, waiting for some suggestions first :)

Comment: Have you investigated using columns in your report? (https://youtu.be/2Y5Tp3cK7KI)

Answer (score 1):

Use a report template for labels. Each label will be one record. It works very well. There are numerous label formats in the Access report dev tool.

Comment: Can you explain more please ??!!